# How to keep the selected field without changing using angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 2 `selectedApp` section, in the first div type `selectedApp` is preselected to `app`. I also have a edit field, if i change the type to `business` in the edit popup section, it gets changed in both edit section and the top div section. What ever i change in edit section, should not reflect to the main div section. Can anyone help me.

HTML:

**Edit Part:**

```
<div class="form-group" >
                  <label style="padding-top: 15px;font-weight: 450" class="showlabel"> Type</label>
                  <ng-select [options]="apps" [(ngModel)]="selectedApp" name="apps" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Type" notFoundMsg="No Type Found" required>
                  </ng-select>
                </div>
```

**Main div:**

```
<div class="form-group tut">
  <ng-select [options]="apps" [ngModel]="selectedApp" (ngModelChange)="typeChanged($event)" name="apps" class='box' placeholder="app" notFoundMsg="No Type Found">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

**Ts:**

```
this.apps = [
        { label:"app",value: "app" },
        { label:"business", value: "business" }
   ];
   this.selectedApp="app";
```

Comment: Try uaing different modles and then when you want to capture the value trigger a event function and assign the value to the main section. That should work.

Comment: Thanks for response, but how to use different models?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one way binding instead of two way binding:

```
<ng-select [options]="apps" [ngModel]="selectedApp" name="apps" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Type" notFoundMsg="No Type Found" required>
</ng-select>
```

In the submit handler you can set the changed value to the original model.

This example code may differ from your form.

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)" #form="ngForm" >

  <ng-select [options]="apps" [ngModel]="selectedApp" name="apps" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Type" notFoundMsg="No Type Found" required>
</ng-select>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

In the save handler you get a `value` with an property called `apps` with the selected value:

```
 save( value: any) {
    console.log(value);
    this.selectedApp = value.apps;
  }
```

Comment: Just use different variable names

Comment: ya it is working now, but the functionalities which was working earlier is not working now

Comment: if i change, app to business in edit field and save the popup, then that edited field must get saved in the business part, but now it is not working so

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular works on 2 way binding, the same variable name reflects the same value everywhere. So, just change the variable name in on of the selects,

You may change the `mainDiv` model as `this.selectedMainApp`

**Edit Part:**

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label style="padding-top: 15px;font-weight: 450" class="showlabel"> Type</label>
    <ng-select [options]="apps" [(ngModel)]="selectedApp" name="apps" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Type" notFoundMsg="No Type Found" required>
    </ng-select>
</div>
```

**Main div:**

```
<div class="form-group tut">
  <ng-select [options]="apps" [ngModel]="selectedMainApp" (ngModelChange)="typeChanged($event)" name="apps" class='box' placeholder="app" notFoundMsg="No Type Found">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

**Ts:**

```
this.apps = [
        { label:"app",value: "app" },
        { label:"business", value: "business" }
   ];
this.selectedApp="app";
this.selectedMainApp="app";
```

Also, what does this function contain, somethings may break if we change this variable name, so you should check all instances and rename it accordingly.